# Determining and Deleting Unused Firmware Files

Tags: linux, firmware

I am trying to slim down an Alpine linux install so that it can fit on a [thin client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client) with very limited storage. After a fresh install I have discovered that the majority of disk space is taken up by firmware files:

[image]

Obviously a large porition of these will be for hardware that is not installed into the system and will never be used. Is there way to determine which firmware files are actually used so that I can delete all of those that aren't?

Comment: Alpine is already a slimmed down Linux. You should ask someone who is involved with the Apline distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firmware actually loaded will have an entry in `/var/log/syslog`. So you can look there to see the ones in use.

The process of firmware loading and how to check/debug it is detailed in [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Firmware):

```
How is Firmware Used?

Each driver for devices that require firmware have some special logic to retrieve firmware from files in /lib/firmware. The basic process is:

    Driver requests firmware file "ar9170.fw"
    The kernel sends an event to udev asking for the firmware
    The udev program runs a script that shoves the data in the firmware file into a special file created by the kernel
    The kernel reads the firmware data from the special file it created and hands the data to the driver
    The driver then does what it needs to do to load the firmware into the device 

If everything goes well you should see something like the following in your /var/log/syslog:

[ 12.860701] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: firmware: requesting lbm-iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode
[ 12.949384] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.24.2.12
```